# Samsung Kies 1.5 not connecting the galaxy fit device

Tags: usb, samsung-kies

I have Samsung Galaxy fit with android 2.2 I have installed Samsung Kies 1.5 since I want to use mobile internet on desktop PC having Windows XP through USB. But when I connect my phone to PC using  data cable Kies keeps on showinf the message 'Connecting the device Please wait' for long time but it never connects. I have installed USB drivers for galaxy fit and I hope there is no prob with that part. Also USB debugging on the device is on. Can anybody help me out of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're planning to use Kies to connect to the device, USB Debugging must be off and the phone's USB mode must be set to Samsung Kies, otherwise Kies won't detect the phone.

Comment: Thanks for your response! But sorry I was wrong in stating my question. The device is getting connected when the USB debugging is off. But how to proceed for tethering? When I tick USB tethering on phone, Kies starts connecting the device again for long time and then no response. Do I also need to tick on Mobile AP option on the device? When I did it, its giving error. Now can you please help me on this?

Comment: I don't have that version combination for testing (running Android 2.3.3 and Win7), but for me tethering works then USB Debugging is on, I plug the device in and then tick USB Tethering. This automatically tethers the devices without the use of Kies. Does this work for you?

Comment: Oh, and you probably need this driver: http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182134

Comment: @ onik oh, It really works without using kies. :) Thanks a lot!